# Printing BFS (Binary Tree) in Level Order with Specific Formatting

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree, breadth-first-search, tree-traversal

To begin with, this question is not a dup of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104644/how-would-you-print-out-the-data-in-a-binary-tree-level-by-level-starting-at-th), but builds on it.

Taking the tree in that question as an example,

```
    1 
   / \
  2   3
 /   / \
4   5   6
```

How would you modify your program to print it so,

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
```

rather than the general

```
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6
```

I'm basically looking for intuitions on the most efficient way to do it - I've got a method involving appending the result to a list, and then looping through it. A more efficient way might be to store the last element in each level as it is popped, and print out a new line afterward.

Ideas?

Comment: depend whether you did too much or to little. too much, remove the / and \ of too little, use arrayindex to know depth

Comment: BTW, why was this question down voted?

Comment: @larsOn Ok, I understand the "remove every second line" comment now. But the first block is only an intuitive representation of the tree as it exists in memory. The third block shows what viksit already knows an algorithm for, and the second block what he would like to obtain instead.

Comment: This was a interview question to me

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Just build one level at a time, e.g.:

```
class Node(object):
  def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
    self.value = value
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

def traverse(rootnode):
  thislevel = [rootnode]
  while thislevel:
    nextlevel = list()
    for n in thislevel:
      print n.value,
      if n.left: nextlevel.append(n.left)
      if n.right: nextlevel.append(n.right)
    print
    thislevel = nextlevel

t = Node(1, Node(2, Node(4, Node(7))), Node(3, Node(5), Node(6)))

traverse(t)
```

**Edit**: if you're keen to get a small saving in maximum consumed "auxiliary" memory (never having simultaneously all this level and the next level in such "auxiliary" memory), you can of course use `collection.deque` instead of `list`, and consume the current level as you go (via `popleft`) instead of simply looping.  The idea of creating one level at a time (as you consume --or iterate on-- the previous one) remains intact -- when you do need to distinguish levels, it's just more direct than using a single big deque plus auxiliary information (such as depth, or number of nodes remaining in a given level).

However, a list that is only appended to (and looped on, rather than "consumed") is quite a bit more efficient than a deque (and if you're after C++ solutions, quite similarly, a std::vector using just `push_back` for building it, and a loop for then using it, is more efficient than a std::deque).  Since all the producing happens first, then all the iteration (or consuming), an interesting alternative **if** memory is tightly constrained might be to use a list anyway to represent each level, then `.reverse` it before you start consuming it (with `.pop` calls) -- I don't have large trees around to check by measurement, but I suspect that this approach would still be faster (and actually less memory-consuming) than `deque` (assuming that the underlying implementation of list [[or std::vector]] actually does recycle memory after a few calls to `pop` [[or `pop_back`]] -- and with the same assumption for deque, of course;-).

Comment: +1 I can see how using two `vector`s for the two levels could be more efficient than using a single `deque`. Especially if `nextLevel` is moved outside the `while`-loop and cleared instead of allocating a new one on the stack for each level (this is the C++ version I'm talking about, I've no idea how memory is managed in Python). This would also allow for very good cache utilization.

Comment: Yes, in C++ you'd definitely want to `swap` the vectors (and clear out the new one -- with the old one's contents -- right after that, if you're looping on it rather than using `pop_back`).  In Python you could do `thislevel[:] = nextlevel`, then if needed `del nextlevel[:]`, with similar effect (though I'm not sure the actual performance improvement would be measurable, it sure can't hurt;-).

Comment: @Alex - thanks for a great answer. The note on the iteration vs consumption of lists was quite informative!

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like [breadth-first traversal](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cs112/spring-2000/breadth-first/) to me.

Breadth-first traversal is implemented with a [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(data_structure)). Here, simply insert in the queue a special token that indicate that a newline must be printed. Each time the token is found, print a newline and re-insert the token in the queue (at the end -- that's the definition of a queue).

Start the algorithm with a queue containing the root followed by the special newline token.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned the BFS part in the title :) I was thinking about the newline in the queue as well, but it seems wrong to intersperse formatting tokens within the queue itself.

Comment: @Viksit Would it be more acceptible to store the depth of each node in the queue? In that case you could simply print a newline each time the current traversal depth is increased.

Comment: Ah, yes, "BFS"... I see what this three-letter acronym means now. Is the "S" for search? Isn't "search" always depth-first (or you built your binary tree wrong in the first place)?

Comment: @Andreas Nice! I was a little reluctant to mix special tokens and nodes in the queue too (but you have to do what you have to do...)

Comment: @Pascal I actually thought a little more and came up with a version that didn't require any extra storage whatsoever :)

Comment: @Pascal - ah, I guess I've always referred to depth first and breadth first traversals as DFS and BFS respectively..

Answer (score 3):

My solution is similar to Alex Martelli's, but I separate traversal of the data structure from processing the data structure. I put the meat of the code into iterLayers to keep printByLayer short and sweet.

```
from collections import deque

class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, lc=None, rc=None):
        self.val = val
        self.lc = lc
        self.rc = rc

    def iterLayers(self):
        q = deque()
        q.append(self)
        def layerIterator(layerSize):
            for i in xrange(layerSize):
                n = q.popleft()
                if n.lc: q.append(n.lc)
                if n.rc: q.append(n.rc)
                yield n.val
        while (q):
            yield layerIterator(len(q))

    def printByLayer(self):
        for layer in self.iterLayers():
            print ' '.join([str(v) for v in layer])

root = Node(1, Node(2, Node(4, Node(7))), Node(3, Node(5), Node(6)))
root.printByLayer()
```

which prints the following when run:

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7
```

Answer (score 3):

This is breadth first search, so you can use a queue and recursively do this in a simple and compact way ...

```
# built-in data structure we can use as a queue
from collections import deque

def print_level_order(head, queue = deque()):
    if head is None:
        return
    print head.data
    [queue.append(node) for node in [head.left, head.right] if node]
    if queue:
        print_level_order(queue.popleft(), queue)
```

Comment: This does BFS traversal but without level distinction (no newline at the end of each level)

Answer (score 2):

why not keep sentinal in queue and check when all the nodes in current level are processed.

```
public void printLevel(Node n) {
    Queue<Integer> q = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>();
    Node sentinal = new Node(-1);
    q.put(n);
    q.put(sentinal);
    while(q.size() > 0) {
        n = q.poll();
        System.out.println(n.value + " "); 
        if (n == sentinal && q.size() > 0) {
           q.put(sentinal); //push at the end again for next level
           System.out.println();
        }
        if (q.left != null) q.put(n.left);
        if (q.right != null) q.put(n.right);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer isn't in Python

Answer (score 1):

A simple Version based on Bread First Search, This code is applicable for graphs in general and can be used for binary trees as well.

```
def printBfsLevels(graph,start):
  queue=[start]
  path=[]
  currLevel=1
  levelMembers=1
  height=[(0,start)]
  childCount=0
  print queue
  while queue:
    visNode=queue.pop(0)
    if visNode not in path:
      if  levelMembers==0:
        levelMembers=childCount
        childCount=0
        currLevel=currLevel+1
      queue=queue+graph.get(visNode,[])
      if levelMembers > 0:
        levelMembers=levelMembers-1
        for node in graph.get(visNode,[]):
          childCount=childCount+1
          height.append((currLevel,node))
      path=path+[visNode]

  prevLevel=None

  for v,k in sorted(height):
        if prevLevel!=v:
          if prevLevel!=None:
            print "\n"
        prevLevel=v
        print k,
  return height

g={1: [2, 3,6], 2: [4, 5], 3: [6, 7],4:[8,9,13]}
printBfsLevels(g,1)


>>> 
[1]
1 

2 3 6 

4 5 6 7 

8 9 13
>>>
```

Another version based on Recursion, which is specific to binary tree

```
class BinTree:
  "Node in a binary tree"
  def __init__(self,val,leftChild=None,rightChild=None,root=None):
    self.val=val
    self.leftChild=leftChild
    self.rightChild=rightChild
    self.root=root
    if not leftChild and not rightChild:
      self.isExternal=True

  def getChildren(self,node):
    children=[]
    if node.isExternal:
      return []
    if node.leftChild:
      children.append(node.leftChild)
    if node.rightChild:
      children.append(node.rightChild)
    return children

  @staticmethod
  def createTree(tupleList):
    "Creates a Binary tree Object from a given Tuple List"
    Nodes={}
    root=None
    for item in treeRep:
      if not root:
        root=BinTree(item[0])
        root.isExternal=False
        Nodes[item[0]]=root
        root.root=root
        root.leftChild=BinTree(item[1],root=root)
        Nodes[item[1]]=root.leftChild
        root.rightChild=BinTree(item[2],root=root)
        Nodes[item[2]]=root.rightChild
      else:
        CurrentParent=Nodes[item[0]]
        CurrentParent.isExternal=False
        CurrentParent.leftChild=BinTree(item[1],root=root)
        Nodes[item[1]]=CurrentParent.leftChild
        CurrentParent.rightChild=BinTree(item[2],root=root)
        Nodes[item[2]]=CurrentParent.rightChild
    root.nodeDict=Nodes
    return root

  def printBfsLevels(self,levels=None):
    if levels==None:
      levels=[self]
    nextLevel=[]
    for node in levels:
      print node.val,
    for node in levels:
      nextLevel.extend(node.getChildren(node))
    print '\n'
    if nextLevel:
      node.printBfsLevels(nextLevel)  


##       1
##     2     3
##   4   5  6  7
##  8

treeRep = [(1,2,3),(2,4,5),(3,6,7),(4,8,None)]
tree= BinTree.createTree(treeRep)
tree.printBfsLevels()

>>> 
1 

2 3 

4 5 6 7 

8 None
```

Answer (score 1):

Here my code prints the tree level by level as well as upside down

```
int counter=0;// to count the toatl no. of elments in the tree

void tree::print_treeupsidedown_levelbylevel(int *array)
{
    int j=2;  
    int next=j;
    int temp=0;
    while(j<2*counter)
    {
        if(array[j]==0)
        break;

        while(array[j]!=-1)
        {
            j++;
        }

        for(int i=next,k=j-1 ;i<k; i++,k--)
        {
            temp=array[i];
            array[i]=array[k];
            array[k]=temp;
        }

        next=j+1;
        j++;
    }

    for(int i=2*counter-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(array[i]>0)
        printf("%d ",array[i]);

        if(array[i]==-1)
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void tree::BFS()
{
    queue<node *>p;

    node *leaf=root;

    int array[2*counter];
    for(int i=0;i<2*counter;i++)
    array[i]=0;

    int count=0;

    node *newline=new node; //this node helps to print a tree level by level
    newline->val=0;
    newline->left=NULL;
    newline->right=NULL;
    newline->parent=NULL;

    p.push(leaf);
    p.push(newline);

    while(!p.empty())
    {
        leaf=p.front();
        if(leaf==newline)
        {
            printf("\n");
            p.pop();
            if(!p.empty())
            p.push(newline);
            array[count++]=-1;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<leaf->val<<" ";
            array[count++]=leaf->val;

            if(leaf->left!=NULL)
            {
                p.push(leaf->left);
            }
            if(leaf->right!=NULL)
            {
                p.push(leaf->right);
            }
            p.pop();
        }
    }
    delete newline;

    print_treeupsidedown_levelbylevel(array);
}
```

Here in my code the function BFS prints the tree level by level, which also fills the data in an int array for printing the tree upside down. (note there is a bit of swapping is used while printing the tree upside down which helps to achieve our goal). If the swapping is not performed then for a tree like

```
                    8
                   /  \
                  1    12
                  \     /
                   5   9
                 /   \
                4     7
                     /
                    6
```

o/p will be

```
  6
  7 4
  9 5
  12 1
  8
```

but the o/p has to be

```
  6
  4 7
  5 9
  1 12
  8
```

this the reason why swapping part was needed in that array.

Comment: That's not python

Answer (score 1):

```
class TNode:
  def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
    self.data = data
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

class BST:
  def __init__(self, root):
    self._root = root

  def bfs(self):
    list = [self._root]
    while len(list) > 0:
        print [e.data for e in list]
        list = [e.left for e in list if e.left] + \
               [e.right for e in list if e.right]
bst = BST(TNode(1, TNode(2, TNode(4), TNode(5)), TNode(3, TNode(6), TNode(7))))
bst.bfs()
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are simply interested in visualizing binary trees (and not so much in the theory behind breadth-first search), there is a `show` function in the [binarytree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/binarytree) package. Applied to the example given in the question,

```
from binarytree import Node, show

root = Node(1)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.left = Node(4)
root.right.left = Node(5)
root.right.right = Node(6)

show(root)
```

which prints

```
    1    
   / \   
  2   3  
 /   / \ 
4   5   6
```

Comment: `from binarytree import build; root = build([3,1,2]); print(root)` Thank you sir

Comment: `build2` was a more intuitive transformation from list to tree for me

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly the same code as provided by Alex Martelli except this is modified for python 3.

```
class Node(object):
  def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
    self.value = value
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

def traverse(rootnode):
  thislevel = [rootnode]
  while thislevel:
    nextlevel = list()
    for n in thislevel:
      print (n.value,' ', end=''),
      if n.left: nextlevel.append(n.left)
      if n.right: nextlevel.append(n.right)
    print(" ")
    thislevel = nextlevel

t = Node(1, Node(2, Node(4, Node(7))), Node(3, Node(5), Node(6)))

traverse(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will print each level of binary tree into new line:

```
public void printbylevel(node root){
    int counter = 0, level = 0;
    Queue<node> qu = new LinkedList<node>();

    qu.add(root);
    level = 1;
    if(root.child1 != null)counter++;
    if(root.child2 != null)counter++;

     while(!qu.isEmpty()){
         node temp = qu.remove();
         level--;
         System.out.print(temp.val);
         if(level == 0 ){
             System.out.println();

             level = counter;
             counter = 0;
         }
        if(temp.child1 != null){
            qu.add(temp.child1);
            counter++;
        }
        if(temp.child2 != null){
            qu.add(temp.child2);
            counter++;
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you expecting is to print the nodes at each level either separated by a space or a comma and the levels be separated by a new line. This is how I would code up the algorithm. We know that when we do a breadth-first search on a graph or tree and insert the nodes in a queue, all nodes in the queue coming out will be either at the same level as the one previous or a new level which is parent level + 1 and nothing else.

So when you are at a level keep printing out the node values and as soon as you find that the level of the node increases by 1, then you insert a new line before starting to print all the nodes at that level.

This is my code which does not use much memory and only the queue is needed for everything.

Assuming the tree starts from the root.

```
queue = [(root, 0)]  # Store the node along with its level. 
prev = 0
while queue:
  node, level = queue.pop(0)
  if level == prev:
    print(node.val, end = "")
  else:
    print()
    print(node.val, end = "")
  if node.left:
    queue.append((node.left, level + 1))
  if node.right:
    queue.append((node.right, level + 1))
  prev = level
```

At the end all you need is the queue for all the processing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python gist which prints the tree by level. The idea behind it is to use BFS and keep a level marker integer which marks the end the last node of the level. This is similar to Naresh's sentinel approach, but without the need of inserting a sentinel inside the queue, since this is accomplished by the level marker.

This algorithm has a space complexity of O(2<sup>tree_height</sup>)

```py
# Print tree by levels - using BFS
# Time complexity of O(n)
# Space complexity: O(2^tree_height)

from collections import deque

class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def print_levels_tree(root: Node):
    q = deque()
    q.append(root)
    level, level_marker = 0, 1
    while q:
        if (level_marker == 0):
            level, level_marker = level + 1, len(q)
            print("", end = '\n')
        level_marker -= 1

        node = q.popleft()

        if (node is None):
            continue

        print(node.data, " ", end = '')

        q.append(node.left)
        q.append(node.right)


# Some examples
tree = Node(19, Node(7, Node(3), Node(11)), Node(19)) 
print_levels_tree(tree)

left = Node(7, Node(3, Node(2), Node(5)), Node(11, None, Node(17, Node(13))))
tree = Node(19, left, Node(43))
print_levels_tree(tree)

left = Node(7, Node(3, Node(2), Node(5)), Node(11, None, Node(17, Node(13))))
right = Node(43, Node(23, None, Node(37, Node(29, None, Node(31)), Node(41))), Node(47, None, Node(53)) )
tree = Node(19, left, right)
print_levels_tree(tree)
```

Which prints something like:

```
19  
7  43  
3  11  23  47  
2  5  17  37  53
```

If you want to use a `\t` separator, it would look like:

```
19  
7   43  
3   11  23  47  
2   5   17  37  53
```

This gist is available at https://gist.github.com/lopespm/993f0af88cf30b7f8c9e17982518b71b

Answer (score 0):

Making use of queues(constant space complexity)

```
def bfs(self, queue=None):
    
    if(queue is None):
        queue = deque([self.root])
        
    elif(not queue):
        return

    currNode  = queue.pop()
    
    print(currNode.data)
    
    if currNode.left:
        queue.appendleft(currNode.left)
        
    if currNode.right:
        queue.appendleft(currNode.right)
    
    self.bfs(queue)
```

Answer (score 0):

**LEVEL ORDER TRAVERSAL of a BT / BST**

In BASH, you can easily implement BT / BST without using any hash arrays/map, etc by simply creating/maintaining nodes in a .txt file.

Here's my crack at it. 2 small functions `print_level()` and `print_root()`, will do. Script can print any level node info from any given user specified root node.

```
#!/bin/bash

print_level(){
 echo $cs

 call_flag=0
 for row in $cs; do if [[ `grep "^${row}:" ~/btree-data.txt` ]]; then call_flag=1; fi; done

 if [[ $call_flag == 1 ]]; then rs="$cs"; print_root; fi
}

print_root(){
  if [[ ${flag} == 0 ]]; then echo "${rs}"; flag=1; fi

  cs=""
  for r in $rs; do cs+="$(grep "^${r}:" ~/btree-data.txt | cut -d':' -f2 | sed "s/,/ /") "; done
  print_level
  echo
}

flag=0
echo -e "\n\n
# It reads a file ~/btree-data.txt (as shown below). 
# -- One can easily implement CRUD operation to maintain BT/BST using a .txt file. 
#
# -- Here .txt file ROW's Format is: NODE:left_leaf_node,right_leaf_node
#
# 100:50,200
# 50:20,60
# 200:300
# 300:350
# 60:55,75
# 20:10,25
# 10:5
# 350:320
# 25:27
# 5:2
# 320:310,325
# 2:3

## ----------------- BTree Diagram -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#                                                             100
#                                             50                               200
#                              20                       60                             300
#                        10          25             55       75                                      350
#                    5                     27                                                  320
#              2                                                                           310     325
#                 3
## ----------------- BTree Diagram -------------------------------------------------------------------------
\n\n"

echo -ne "\n-- Enter which root: "; read rs

print_root
echo -e "\n\n"
```

**Which when you run, spits**:

**$** ./btree-bash-level-print.sh

```
# It reads a file ~/btree-data.txt (as shown below). 
# -- One can easily implement CRUD operation to maintain BT/BST using a .txt file. 
#
# -- Here .txt file ROW's Format is: NODE:left_leaf_node,right_leaf_node
#
# 100:50,200
# 50:20,60
# 200:300
# 300:350
# 60:55,75
# 20:10,25
# 10:5
# 350:320
# 25:27
# 5:2
# 320:310,325
# 2:3

## ----------------- BTree Diagram -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#                                                             100
#                                             50                               200
#                              20                       60                             300
#                        10          25             55       75                                      350
#                    5                     27                                                  320
#              2                                                                           310     325
#                 3
## ----------------- BTree Diagram -------------------------------------------------------------------------




-- Enter which root: 100
100
50 200
20 60 300
10 25 55 75 350
5 27 320
2 310 325
3
```

For **root (300)**,

```
-- Enter which root: 300
300
350
320
310 325
```

For **root (50)**,

```
-- Enter which root: 50
50
20 60
10 25 55 75
5 27
2
3
```

Answer (score -1):

A version that doesn't require extra storage:

```
std::deque<Node> bfs;
bfs.push_back(start);
int nodesInThisLayer = 1;
int nodesInNextLayer = 0;
while (!bfs.empty()) {
    Node front = bfs.front();
    bfs.pop_front();
    for (/*iterate over front's children*/) {
        ++nodesInNextLayer;
        nodes.push_back(child);
    }
    std::cout << node.value;
    if (0 == --nodesInThisLayer) {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        nodesInThisLayer = nodesInNextLayer; 
        nodesInNextLayer = 0;
    } else {
        std::cout << " ";
    }
}
```

P.S. sorry for the C++ code, I'm not very fluent in Python yet.

Comment: @Andreas - nice! I was looking at a version of this algorithm where I would store the "level" or "depth" of where the loop was (so, this tree would have 3 levels). The problem I faced was how to increment this level each time. Looks like your approach of storing the depth of each element works better.

Comment: @Viksit If you look closer I only stores two extra integers, one for how many nodes are left to process in the current level and one for how many nodes are left to process in the next level (Or was this what you meant?)