# How to construct a Character-based Python BFS Search With

Tags: python, tree, breadth-first-search

I'm new to Python, and trying to construct a **character-based** BFS tree which prints the Parent-child relationships. A closely related solution, but is a **number-based** tree, is found in this
found here [Printing BFS (Binary Tree) in Level Order with _specific formatting_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894846/printing-bfs-binary-tree-in-level-order-with-specific-formatting) , specifically the following example as taken from the reference:

```
def printBfsLevels(graph,start):
queue=[start]
path=[]
currLevel=1
levelMembers=1
height=[(0,start)]
childCount=0
print queue
while queue:
visNode=queue.pop(0)
if visNode not in path:
  if  levelMembers==0:
    levelMembers=childCount
    childCount=0
    currLevel=currLevel+1
  queue=queue+graph.get(visNode,[])
  if levelMembers > 0:
    levelMembers=levelMembers-1
    for node in graph.get(visNode,[]):
      childCount=childCount+1
      height.append((currLevel,node))
  path=path+[visNode]

prevLevel=None

for v,k in sorted(height):
    if prevLevel!=v:
      if prevLevel!=None:
        print "\n"
    prevLevel=v
    print k,
return height

g={1: [2, 3,6], 2: [4, 5], 3: [6, 7],4:[8,9,13]}
printBfsLevels(g,1)
```

Suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: replace the numbers in g to characters?

Comment: Can you give me an example? When I try substituting "1" with "A", e.g., I receive the error, "A is not defined".

Answer (score -1):

For graphs I use the networkx library.

You should look at http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/algorithms.traversal.html