# Printing levels of Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search-tree

I have a binary search tree data structure class that holds nodes which are objects in the side the class that acts like a binary search tree.

The class is too long to post here, but basically this is how it works.
If I want to print the top value of the bst, I would say

```
print (self._root)
```

If I wanted to move to the left side of the tree (same with to go to the right, just put right instead of left) , I would say

```
print (self._root._left)
```

I hope this is enough so you can help me with my problem

So onto my problem, if I have a bst like:

```
      6
     / \
    3   8
   / \   \
  1  4   10
```

I want to be able to print out:

```
6

3
8

1
4
10
```

I have written a recursive traverse function:

```
def traverse(self):

        a = []
        self._traverse_aux(self._root, a)   
        return a

def _traverse_aux(self, node, a):

        if node is not None:
            self._traverse_aux(node._left, a)
            a.append(node._value)
            self._traverse_aux(node._right, a)
        return
```

How ever, this prints the values in a single array:

```
[1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

How can I get it to print the way I want above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing BFS (Binary Tree) in Level Order with \_specific formatting\_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894846/printing-bfs-binary-tree-in-level-order-with-specific-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Optimally, you're going to want to answer this recursively. This type of traversal in particular is called Breadth-First.
[Here](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall11/CSCI-UA.0102-001/Notes11.html) are some notes on traversal of binary search trees which might be useful to you, although they are in java.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894846/printing-bfs-binary-tree-in-level-order-with-specific-formatting) is also a very similar (possibly duplicate) question, although as opposed to solving it recursively a solution is given using loops.