# Binary tree of directories UNIX

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a task to create a binary tree of directories in bash shell, the depth is given as a first argument of the script. Every directory has to be named with the second argument + the depth of the tree which the directory is in.

Example: ./tree.sh 3 name should create the following structure:

```
                        name11
                      /        \
                name21          name22
                /    \          /    \
            name31  name32    name33 name34
```

I don't really have an idea how to do this, Can't even start. It is harder than anything i have done in bash up until now.. Any help will be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to do this in a language other than Bash?

Comment: What do you do if a directory has more than two subdirectories?

Comment: No, not really, never worked on problems like this. That is why i am asking for help :)

Comment: Is that really `name32`, or should that be `name33`.  It really ought to be `name221`, or even `nameRL` with the root directory being simply `name`

Comment: If you can accurately describe the names of the two directories that you will create inside `nameXY`, you are more than half way to solving the problem.

Comment: It is name 33 i will fix it now

Comment: @mouseepaad: Do you only want to print a tree with three levels or do you want to create the real structure of a [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) in variables/arrays?

Comment: Create the directories only... the tree is shown for example how should they look like. With number of levels that is equal to the second command line argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With recursion:

```
#!/bin/bash

level=$1
current_level=$2; current_level=${current_level:=1}
last_number=$3; last_number=${last_number:=1}
prefix="name"

# test to stop recursion
[[ $level -eq $(($current_level-1)) ]] && exit

# first node
new_number=$(($current_level*10+$last_number*2-1))
mkdir "$prefix$new_number"
(
  cd "$prefix$new_number"
  $0 $level $(($current_level+1)) $(($last_number*2-1)) &
)

# second node, not in level 1
if [[ $current_level -ne 1 ]]; then
  new_number=$(($current_level*10+$last_number*2))
  mkdir "$prefix$new_number"
  cd "$prefix$new_number"
  $0 $level $(($current_level+1)) $(($last_number*2)) &
fi
```

Test with `./tree.sh 3`

Comment: Be carefull with larger numbers to avoid a [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).

Comment: To prevent a fork bomb in linux, edit the number of processes a user may create, e.g. `ulimit -u 30`

Answer (score 0):

Even though other languages are more suitable in implementing a link list, I don't know why this post got a negative vote.

Here's this expert, shared something good for searching, take a look:
https://gist.github.com/iestynpryce/4153007

**NOTE:** *An implementation of a Binary Sort Tree in Bash. Object-like behaviour has been faked using **eval**. Remember that eval in shell scripting can be evil.* BT and BST have difference, you can google it.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Binary search tree is of the form:
#               10
#              /  \
#             /    \
#            4      16
#           / \    /  
#          1   7  12
#

# Print the binary search tree by doing a recursive call on each node.
# Call the left node, print the value of the current node, call the right node.
# Cost is O(N), where N is the number of elements in the tree, as we have to
# visit each node once.
print_binary_search_tree() {
    local node="$*";
    # Test is the node id is blank, if so return
    if [ "${node}xxx" == "xxx" ]; then
        return;
    fi
    print_binary_search_tree $(eval ${node}.getLeftChild)
    echo $(${node}.getValue)
    print_binary_search_tree $(eval ${node}.getRightChild)
}

### Utility functions to generate a BST ###

# Define set 'methods'
set_node_left() {
    eval "${1}.getLeftChild()  { echo "$2"; }"
}
set_node_right() {
    eval "${1}.getRightChild() { echo "$2"; }"
}
set_node_value() {
    eval "${1}.getValue()      { echo "$2"; }"
}

# Generate unique id:
gen_uid() {
    # prefix 'id' to the uid generated to guarentee
    # it starts with chars, and hence will work as a
    # bash variable
    echo "id$(uuidgen|tr -d '-')";
}

# Generates a new node 'object'
new_node() {
    local node_id="$1";
    local value="$2";
    local left="$3";
    local right="$4";
    eval "${node_id}set='set'";
    eval "set_node_value $node_id $value";
    eval "set_node_left $node_id $right";
    eval "set_node_right $node_id $right";
}

# Inserts a value into a tree with a root node with identifier '$id'.
# If the node, hence the tree does not exist it creates it.
# If the root node is at the either end of the list you'll reach the
# worst case complexity of O(N), where N is the number of elements in 
# the tree. (Average case will be 0(logN).)
tree_insert() {
    local id="$1"
    local value="$2";
    # If id does not exist, create it
    if [ -z "$(eval "echo \$${id}set")" ]; then
        eval "new_node $id $value";
    # If id exists and the value inserted is less than or equal to 
    # the id's node's value. 
    # - Go down the left branch
    elif [[ $value -le $(${id}.getValue) ]]; then
        # Go down to an existing left node if it exists, otherwise
        # create it.
        if [ "$(eval ${id}.getLeftChild)xxx" != "xxx" ]; then
            tree_insert $(eval ${id}.getLeftChild) $value
        else
            local uid=$(gen_uid);
            tree_insert $uid $value;
            set_node_left $id $uid;
        fi
    # Else go down the right branch as the value inserted is larger
    # than the id node's value.
    else 
        # Go down the right node if it exists, else create it
        if [ "$(eval ${id}.getRightChild)xxx" != "xxx" ]; then
            tree_insert $(eval ${id}.getRightChild) $value
        else
            local uid=$(gen_uid);
            tree_insert $uid $value;
            set_node_right $id $uid;
        fi
    fi
}

# Insert an unsorted list of numbers into a binary search tree
for i in 10 4 16 1 7 12; do
    tree_insert bst $i;
done

# Print the binary search tree out in order
print_binary_search_tree bst
```

**Actually**, I think, it's super easy to implement aa BST in **BASH**.

**How**:
Just create a **:)** damn .txt **:)** FILE for maintaining the BST.

Here, I'm not going to show how you can implement the CRUD operation for inserting/populating or deleting/updating a BST nodes if implemented using a simple .txt file, but it works as far as printing values. I'll work on it and share the solution soon.

**Here is my solution**: Just FYSA In BASH, I used a .txt file approach and tried for printing the same from any root node here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67341334/1499296