# How to create a Binary Tree in Python?

Tags: python, binary-tree

```
# Binary tree node
class node:
     
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.left=None
        self.right=None
        self.data=data
  
# Function to create a new
# Binary node
def newNode(data):
    return node(data)

def t():
    root=newNode("A")
    root.left = newNode("B")
    root.right = newNode("C")
    root.left.left = newNode("D")
    root.left.right = newNode("G")
    root.right.right = newNode("E")
    root.right.right.left = newNode("F")
    

print(t)
```

Hi, I have tried to create a Binary Tree above but I did not managed to print out the binary tree when I print "t".
Instead of a Binary Tree, it shows me this:
[image]

Comment: Well `t` is a function... Did you mean to call it - `t()`? Still you will not see anything printed, because `t` doesn't print anything...

Comment: You haven't actually called `t`. The thing is, even if you did, it still wouldn't print out anything meaningful. What do you want to print out?

Comment: @KevinSheng I would like to print out the all the nodes in the Binary tree :(

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34012886/print-binary-tree-level-by-level-in-python

Comment: You may want to add another function to your node class, that prints its data and subnodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `t` just creates a binary tree. If you want to print a tree you need to traverse it and print it. Depending on the way you want to print a tree, there are different traversal techniques,  the popular of which are `Inorder`, `Preorder` and `Postorder`. Check this [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) for tree traversal methods.

Your code has to be extended to do the required tree traversal. Sample is below:

```
# Binary tree node
class node:
     
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.left=None
        self.right=None
        self.data=data
  
# Function to create a new
# Binary node
def newNode(data):
    return node(data)

def t():
    root=newNode("A")
    root.left = newNode("B")
    root.right = newNode("C")
    root.left.left = newNode("D")
    root.left.right = newNode("G")
    root.right.right = newNode("E")
    root.right.right.left = newNode("F")
    return root


def in_order(root):
    if root:
        in_order(root.left)
        print (root.data)
        in_order(root.right) 

def pre_order(root):
    if root:
        print (root.data)
        pre_order(root.left)
        pre_order(root.right)
        
def post_order(root):
    if root:        
        post_order(root.left)
        post_order(root.right)
        print (root.data)
        
root = t()


print ("In Order")
in_order(root)
print ("Pre Order")
pre_order(root)
print ("Post Order")
post_order(root)
```

Output:

```
In Order
D
B
G
A
C
F
E
Pre Order
A
B
D
G
C
E
F
Post Order
D
G
B
F
E
C
A
```

Comment: hi so what if i turned "t" as an object for binary tree

Comment: But you still have to write the code to print it. Since it is a custom data structure you are building you still have to tell how to print it.

Answer (score 2):

So two things:

When you do `print(t)` instead of `print(t())`, there's a difference. `print(t)` prints the function object itself, whereas `print(t())` prints the result returned by the function.

However, even if you do the latter, you'll print `None` because `t()` doesn't return anything. You'll need to return `root` from `t()` and also you'll have to write a special function that iterates through the tree to print each node's value (if that's what you want)

Here's an example:

```py
# Binary tree node
class node:
     
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.left=None
        self.right=None
        self.data=data
  
# Function to create a new
# Binary node
def newNode(data):
    return node(data)

def t():
    root=newNode("A")
    root.left = newNode("B")
    root.right = newNode("C")
    root.left.left = newNode("D")
    root.left.right = newNode("G")
    root.right.right = newNode("E")
    root.right.right.left = newNode("F")
    return root
    

def treeToString(root, level=0):
  ret = "\t"*level+repr(root.data)+"\n"
  if root.left != None:
      ret += treeToString(root.left, level+1)
  if root.right != None:
      ret += treeToString(root.right, level+1)
  return ret

print(treeToString(t()))


# if you want to assign the tree to an object then do this:

tree = t()
print(tree.left.data)
print(tree.right.data)
```

Comment: because i want to create a next function call the print_leaf_nodes_bylevel(t.root, level) @Aziz Sonawalla  hence, i would like to create a binary tree function name "t" first before i can do t.root

Comment: You cannot do `t.root` because `t` is a function, not an object. Please look at the code I added

Comment: ohh no Thanks @Aziz Sonawalla Now my question was how to create a binary tree as an object t

Comment: as I dont know what t.root at first

Comment: oh, in that case just do `t = t()` (but I suggest renaming the function then). I'll add the sample code above

Answer (score 0):

```
# Binary tree node
class node:
     
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.left=None
        self.right=None
        self.data=data
  
# Function to create a new
# Binary node
def newNode(data):
    return node(data)

def tree():
    root=newNode("A")
    root.left = newNode("B")
    root.right = newNode("C")
    root.left.left = newNode("D")
    root.left.right = newNode("G")
    root.right.right = newNode("E")
    root.right.right.left = newNode("F")
    return root

t = tree()

print(t.left.data)
print(t.right.data)
print(t.root)
```

How do I access the root of the tree from here?

I have tried printing t.root but it seemed to have an error :(