# Printing Binary Tree in Level Order without Left or Right in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree

This question is seeking an alternative to the answers given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894846/printing-bfs-binary-tree-in-level-order-with-specific-formatting).

How can I create a string which has each level of the tree on a new line with the following Binary Tree Structure:

```
# A Node is an object
# - value : Number
# - children : List of Nodes
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, children):
        self.value = value
        self.children = children
```

My problem is that I'm used to Tree Structures like this:

```
class Node(object):
  def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
    self.value = value
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
```

Here is an example tree:

```
exampleTree = Node(1,[Node(2,[]),Node(3,[Node(4,[Node(5,[]),Node(6,[Node(7,[])])])])])
```

That would print as:

```
1 
23
4
56
7
```

Any help or ideas on how to create a definition using that new structure would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `list.extend`to add child nodes instead of `append`ing them one by one.

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, value, children):
    self.value = value
    self.children = children


def traverse(root):
  curr = [root]
  while curr:
    next_level = []
    for n in curr:
      print(n.value, end='')
      next_level.extend(n.children)
    print()
    curr = next_level

exampleTree = Node(1,[Node(2,[]),Node(3,[Node(4,[Node(5,[]),Node(6,[Node(7,[])])])])])

traverse(exampleTree)
```

prints

```
1
23
4
56
7
```

(For anyone who didn't read the question, this is entirely derivative of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894914/6779307))

Answer (score 0):

You could use a queue to perform a BFS on your tree:

```
try:
    from queue import Queue # Python 3
except ImportError:
    from Queue import Queue # Python 2
q = Queue() # create new queue
q.put(root) # where "root" is the root node of the tree
while not q.empty():
    curr = q.get() # get next node from queue
    print(curr.value) # get node's value
    for child in curr.children:
        q.put(child) # add each child to the queue
```

Note that this solution works for all trees, not just binary

EDIT: Sorry, didn't realize that you wanted all the ones in the same level to be in the same line of output. Use the other solution (or modify mine appropriately)

Comment: I'd recommend against using `queue.Queue` if you just want a normal data structure. That class is intended for synchronized communication between threads (it has locks, etc., which you don't need). Instead, use `collections.deque` (pronounced deck, and officially meaning double-ended-queue), which has only the stuff you need. The `queue.Queue` class uses a `deque` internally!