# How to print tree

Tags: c#

I want to print tree, which contains in a `List<Node>`. Anybody help me

Class Node has 4 fields:

```
    public char Symbol { get; set; }
    public int Frequency { get; set; }
    public Node Right { get; set; }
    public Node Left { get; set; }
```

Comment: we need more information, what do you want to print?

Comment: You have three operations at your disposal:
1. Printing the left subtree
2. Printing the right subtree
3. Printing the symbol/frequency of the current node.

The important decision in your exercise is to decide what order you should print those three things. Do it recursively for the trees.

Answer (score 0):

Tree traversal is probably the thing that you are interested in. You may read about it for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal). And if it is a typical Binary Search Tree then you should probably consider the In-Order tree walk to print the elements in an ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell us Breadth first or Depth first ? or some other ways to traversal the tree

Someone has already provide the solution of Breadth first [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104644/how-would-you-print-out-the-data-in-a-binary-tree-level-by-level-starting-at-t)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/AharonSambol/PrettyPrintTreeCSharp

I know I'm late.. But I made this solution which works not only for simple trees but also for more complex ones (such as multi-lined strings)

Example output:

[image]